# How to resume failed/interrupted downloads with SFTP?

Tags: shell, sftp, git-bash, openssh

I am using GitBash and I am downloading a file greater than 10GB and it stopped halfway. I don't want to download the whole file again from start. How can I start the download from where it was stopped with SFTP?
I have tried reget command it showed cannot download non-regular file.

Answer (score 37):

*(Assuming, you are using OpenSSH `sftp`),* use its [`reget` command](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#reget). It has the same syntax as the `get`, except that it starts a transfer from the end of an existing local file.

The same effect has `-a` switch to the [`get` command](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#get) or [global command-line `-a` switch of `sftp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#a).

---

*You need OpenSSH 6.3 and later [on the client side] for these features.*

Comment: in case anyone wondering how to do it with failed upload `reput <filname>`